# Electron js slow startup

Tags: node.js, performance, electron

Electron is really slow when trying to start any app with `electron .` command, `electron index.js` is not working any better. I don't know whats the problem but when i start using same code on a fresh install of node and electron on another pc it starts super fast. This pc is faster than the other one so it can't  be that. It takes about 15 seconds and it is really annoying when trying to debug. Even when loading local files it's still slow. Disabling my antivirus is not helping

node -v takes about a second
and
npm -v takes about 3 seconds

Specs:

- OS: Windows 10
- Antivirus: McAfee antivirus
- Processor: Intel i7 8700K
- Hard drive: Samsung 1tb ssd sata
- Ram: 2*4 G

Comment: Without knowing your machine this may not be answerable, but you can increase your chances by adding more information like your OS and whether you have installed antivirus software that may intercept your file system calls. Do you have this problem with node.js too?

Comment: @Rhayene
I edited it so you have more info

Comment: Are you able to temporarily disable McAfee to look whether it is the culprit?

Comment: @Rhayene That didnt work ):

Comment: It was only a guess, because we had problems with antivirus on a machine. Running performance checks on pcs is not my forte - maybe someone else can help you with this. If you don't have a fresh node installation, you can try to uninstall and reinstall node - maybe something is bodged. I'm sorry that I can't help you further.

Comment: @Rhayene I reinstalled node and nothing helped. But thanks for trying!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This got fixed after installing RTX Voice for some reason.